# Development Tablet Recommendations

Tags: android, tablet-pc

After moving from Verizon to Sprint and buying several Android phones (EVO 4G), I became interested in developing Android applications.  I have some programming experience (35+ years with various software firms (e.g. Cray Research, IBM, Oracle)) and would like to finally do some programming for myself.

I'm looking for recommendations on Android tablets.  After looking at the marketplace, I realized it really is "buyer beware" and would appreciate hearing from other programmers.  After all why reinvent the wheel or take graduate courses at the University of Hard Knocks.  I thought about getting one of the Google dev phones, but I'd like to support tablets (and phones).

I suspect I'll end up with two tablets and then use one of my phones during the beta testing.  As for features, I'm open other than it needs WIFI (but not 3G or 4G) and show be a good solid development platform.

Bert Moshier

Comment: The only serious Android tablet I've seen is the samsung galaxy, but its not out yet.  I think you might be a bit early if you are looking for a selection of tablets.

Comment: [cross post](http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/android-tablet-discussions/1697-looking-development-tablet-recommendataions-please.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to use the tablet for. For personal use I use an Apple iPad or a Samsung Galaxy but for busines use, ie: to give to customers to put next to their computer monitor to show some alerts I use the cheapest tablet I can find, which is usually around $100 for a cheap android tablet.